# Is it possible to force Drupal 8 core Jquery to go to the header?

Tags: jquery, drupal-8

I was simply wondering if it's possible to move (only) JQ core file to the top of the website instead of before the`</body>` html tag.  I know it's not the best practice but the Revolution Slider I'm using won't work if JQ is not loaded before slider's scripts, I know, it's weird but it's the way they created it I guess :p.

I've modified core.libraries.yml (actually I created a patch and reverse patch to apply when I update Drupal) and I've included a `header:true` statement in order to JQuery to go to the .  This is not a good idea to modify drupal's core, this is why I'm looking for a better solution.

Or maybe the best way to achieve what I'm looking for is to override core JQuery with my own JQuery so I could place it wherever I want?  I have no idea if it's possible :)

Thank's!

Comment: Why don't you just let jQuery stay where it is and include the revolution slider JS after it?

Comment: Well, I already tried that.  And sadly it doesn't work ^^' it looks like I have to include the required JS before generating the slider..

Comment: How did you try to include the slider JS? Because if you do it the right way, it should come after jQuery (and all core JS) automatically.

Comment: As usual : in my theme.libraries.yml file.  It goes after drupal's jQuery, but it was not working even if it should've :/.  I just switched jquery's core (just to give it a try) so it goes to the header, and it worked ^^'

Comment: Hm, that is strange. What does the error in the browser console say?

Comment: as far as I remember, it said "jQuery is not defined".  But yeah it's weird since ... it was defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're getting a "jQuery is not defined" error but your javascript file is after jQuery in the list, it's likely your problem is somewhere else.  Maybe you have some inline javascript code in your template?

One way to push jquery to the header without having to modify core.libraries.yml is to make sure you have these configurations in your THEME.libraries.yml:

```
global-styling:
  header: true
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

This assumes you have the usual global-styling library and that it is listed in your THEME.info.yml as well.

You may need to clear cache to see the results.